# Doctrine entitymanager clear doesn't fully clear

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this piece of code:

```
$entityManager->clear('Reza\MyBundle\Entity\ListItem');

$identity = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getIdentityMap();
foreach ($identity as $class => $objectlist) {
    if ($class == 'Reza\MyBundle\Entity\ListItem') {
        print "didn't fully clear, exiting..\n ";
        exit;
    }
}
```

You would think that after I pass in the classname to clear, you should not see those objects in the unit of work anymore, but by looking at the source I noticed that when you pass an argument to the `clear()` function it **only detaches** entities of that type. On the other hand, if I don't pass any arguments to `clear()` it detaches and does in fact clear, so the above code does not hit line 138, exit. So that means it not only detaches all entities, but also clears the unit of work.

Anyone has any thoughts on this? Should I file a bug with doctrine?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I would say that technically it is not a bug as `clear()` works as described in the documentation, see Doctrine2 [API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#_clear), [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) and [source code](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/e018bb83f0d2c0e92560c4644ec9f4d008cb741b/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L2350) ([current version](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php)).

The `clear()` method is just a way to `detach()` all entities or entities of a specified type.
It can be thought as a "Multi-Detach", its purpose does not extend past detaching.

When detaching all entities using `clear()` Doctrine detaches the entities using the most efficient method possible. In the process the Identity Map Array is set to an empty `array()`.
This will give the appearance of what I believe you are referring to as cleared.

```
$entityManager->clear();
$identity = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getIdentityMap(); 
//This will return a an empty array() to $identity
//therefore $identity['Reza\MyBundle\Entity\ListItem'] would be undefined
```

If we assume that data was retrieved for an entity of `Reza\MyBundle\Entity\ListItem`.
Then in the following example we can see that the unit of work has at least 1 `Reza\MyBundle\Entity\ListItem` object.

```
$identity = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getIdentityMap();
$count = count($identity['Reza\MyBundle\Entity\ListItem']);
// $count would be > 0;
```

However, when you use `clear($entityName)` and clear by entity type, the cleared/detached entities are removed from the unit of work, it is only the array key `[$entityName]` that remains, not any of the objects.

```
$entityManager->clear('Reza\MyBundle\Entity\ListItem');
$identity = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getIdentityMap(); 
$count = count($identity['Reza\MyBundle\Entity\ListItem']);
//$count would be == 0. All Objects cleared/detached.
```

This functionality is all that is specified by the documentation.

I do think a **feature request** is in order, to make it work more consistently.
When invoking `clear($entityName)` Doctrine should `unset()` the remaining key thereby making it undefined (cleared). This would allow us to more easily write code that would work whether we used `clear()` or `clear($entityName)`.

Comment: Everything was so simple. It remains only the name of the class in map, but entities disappear. Good job!

Comment: @hcoat Please don't link (3) against a specific line in the master branch on GitHub as it will most likely change (it already did). Pick a tagged release instead.

Comment: Does anybody know if there already is a feature request to make this feature more consistently?