# EntityManager: only clear entities of a certain type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entitymanager

**TL;DR: How do I use `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::clear()` using `$entityName`?**

Let's say I've got a `Post` entity with an `Author` and a `Category`. I want add posts to my database (random, from a CSV-file or whatsoever). I'm having performance issues while adding the data. The memory usage increases and it slows down the process, but I don't know how I can (partly) clear the EntityManager.

This is the loop where the magic happens:

```
$batchSize = 250;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    //$post['author'] is instance of Acme\BlogBundle\Author
    $post = new Post($post['author'], $post['category']);
    $em->persist($post);

    if ($i % $batchSize == 0) {
        $entity = '??';
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear($entityName);

        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
}
```

This throws a `Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: A new entity was found through the relationship Acme\BlogBundle\Post#author`. That is correct, since the `Author` is managed by the EntityManager that has been cleared.

This is the clear method:

```
namespace Doctrine\ORM;
class EntityManager implements EntityManagerInterface {
 /**
 * Clears the EntityManager. All entities that are currently managed
 * by this EntityManager become detached.
 *
 * @param string|null $entityName if given, only entities of this type will get detached
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function clear($entityName = null)
{
    $this->unitOfWork->clear($entityName);
}

}
```

Since I want to clear the Posts, but want to keep the Author and Category entity types, I expected that `$entityName = 'Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Post'`, `$entityName = get_class($post);` or `$entityName = Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Post::class` would help, but unfortunately it doesn't clear anything.

How do I correctly use this parameter?

Comment: i guess you have to pass sth similiar to `"AcmeBlogBundle:Post"`

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061870/doctrine-entitymanager-clear-doesnt-fully-clear ?

Comment: @johnSmith No, doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @TobiasXy Yes, I think so. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a classname as entityName to the entitymanager clear method, but it has to be exactly the same as doctrine unit of work has stored in his identity map. To get the right one you should do something like that:

```
$classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($post));
$entityName = $classMetadata->rootEntityName;
```

Comment: `$entityName` returns `Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Post`, so unfortunately it didn't work either.

Comment: For me, it seems, that your memory problem could be caused by something different.
If you are using symfony console commands, please ensure using --env=prod to avoid logging-buffer

Comment: At least, if you just need entities to make relations on your database, you can use $em->getReference($entityName, $id) which could save some time